# Is there an in-universe reason that Big Daddies must be killed before harvesting Little Sisters?

Tags: bioshock

In *BioShock*, Little Sisters, carriers of ADAM, are protected by Big Daddies.

In-game, you must kill the Big Daddies before harvesting the ADAM from Little Sisters. Is there any reason, in-universe, that you can’t take the ADAM from Little Sisters before killing their Big Daddies, or is it just for gameplay purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly for gameplay balance, but it did seem to me to be a reasonably justified restriction.  Presumably, doing the harvesting properly is potentially tricky and somewhat time-consuming process; you have the get the nudibranch inside the Little Sister disconnected and out of her body without damaging it.  The game is deliberately vague about what this gruesome process entails, including how long it takes.

During the extraction process, you do not want the dedicated Big Daddy protector to be there to interfere.  As a result, the Big Daddy needs to be eliminated first.